# Object error thrown at arcpy.DeleteField_management line?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

My script keeps giving me an error, "RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool", from the line `arcpy.DeleteField_management("blocks", field)`. I'm relatively new to ArcPy and still not sure which tools give me results/object outputs. I've tried using `arcpy.CopyFeatures_management` & `arcpy.mapping.Layer`, but I had no luck.

```
import arcpy
import os
import datetime as date

# Connect to database
#arcpy.CreateDatabaseConnection_management(r"\\bctsdata.bcgov\data\GIS_WORKSPACE\Projects\Google_Earth\PythonScript", "DBP06.sde")
arcpy.AddMessage("Establishing database connection...")
dbConn = "Database Connections\\DBP06.sde"
arcpy.env.workspace = r"\\bctsdata.bcgov\data\tst_root\GIS_WORKSPACE\Projects\Google_Earth"

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Assign variables
originalBlock = "Database Connections\\DBP06.sde\\FORESTVIEW.SV_BLOCK"#os.path.join(dbConn, "\\FORESTVIEW.SV_BLOCK")
originalRoad = os.path.join(dbConn, "\\FOREST.migration_dataset/FOREST.ROAD_SHAPE")
blockSym = r"\\bctsdata.bcgov\data\tst_root\GIS_WORKSPACE\Projects\Google_Earth\PythonScript\layer_symbology\Blocks.lyr"
roadSym = r"\\bctsdata.bcgov\data\tst_root\GIS_WORKSPACE\Projects\Google_Earth\PythonScript\layer_symbology\Roads.lyr"
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]

# Start of block feature creation
arcpy.AddMessage("Preparing block layer...")

# Select block features by Div# and copy to in_memory
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(originalBlock, "blocks")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("blocks", "NEW_SELECTION", 'DIVI_DIV_NBR = 18')
#fcBlock = arcpy.mapping.Layer("blocks")
#arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("blocks", "in_memory/fcBlock")

# Remove unnecessary fields from in_memory block layer
keepFields = ['LICENCE_ID', 'BLOCK_ID', 'UBI', 'CUTB_BLOCK_STATE']

fields = arcpy.ListFields("blocks")

for field in fields:
    if field.name not in set(keepFields):
        arcpy.DeleteField_management("blocks", field)

# Update symbology of in_memory block layer
arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(df, "in_memory/fcBlock", blockSym, False)

# Start of road feature creation
arcpy.AddMessage("Preparing road layer...")

# Select road features by Div# and copy to in_memory
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(originalRoad, "roads")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("roads", "NEW_SELECTION", 'DIVI_DIV_NBR = 18')
#fcBlock = arcpy.mapping.Layer("blocks")
fcRoad = arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("road", "in_memory/fcRoad")

# Remove unnecessary fields from in_memory road layer
keepFields = ['ROAD_NAME', 'RSTA_ROAD_STATE', 'ROAD_SEQ_NBR', 'DIVI_DIV_NBR']

for field in arcpy.ListFields(fcRoad):
    if field.name not in set(keepFields):
        arcpy.DeleteField_management(fcRoad, field)

# Update symbology of in_memory road layer
arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(df, fcRoad, roadSym, False)

# use 'Map to KML' tool to generate KML for Google Earth
arcpy.AddMessage("Exporting to KML...")
arcpy.MapToKML_conversion(mxd, df, os.path.join("BlocksAndRoadUpdate_", date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')), 300000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Data Type for the drop_field parameter should be String. If you look at all the examples in the [help](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.9/tool-reference/data-management/delete-field.htm), what is passed in the `field.name`.